# IdentityServer3 - When is username/password enough for token

Tags: identityserver3

I am trying to implement authentication/authorization using IdentityServer3 for my ASP.NET Web API v2. The client is a simple HTML and jQuery application. The client uses AJAX to make some API calls to my back-end API.

I remain confused on the need for a `client secret`. Shouldn't the username/password combination be enough for IdentityServer3 to hand back a JWT token?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the flow. Implicit flow (which sounds right for your scenario) does not need a client secret.

Whenever you are communicating with the token endpoint, you need a client secret.